# How to start a private network on 2 computers?

Tags: nodes, private-network, network

I've done the [Start a private network tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/). However, in this tutorial, they run `two-nodes` on the same computer with different `ports`. Now I want to run a private network with different computers but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I've not tried it on a local network - my nodes are all either on a single machine or in the cloud - but there are a couple of options that suggest it'll probably just work on the same private IP address subnet, if you're using --dev.

```
        --allow-private-ipv4               
            Always accept connecting to private IPv4 addresses (as specified in
            [RFC1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)). Enabled by default for chains marked as "local" in their
            chain specifications, or when `--dev` is passed

        --discover-local                   
            Enable peer discovery on local networks.
            
            By default this option is `true` for `--dev` or when the chain type is `Local`/`Development` and false
            otherwise.
```

If it doesn't work without encouragement, you could give the two nodes the other node as a bootnode (technically only one needs to be able to find the other for it to work).  Bootnodes either in the chainspec or on the command line.

```
        --bootnodes <ADDR>...                                        
            Specify a list of bootnodes
```

The format for bootnodes is:

```
 --bootnodes /ip4/<ip_address>/tcp/<p2p_port>/p2p/12D3KooWC1RbgqfcM219TvGoNfU3ZRQcBxWDiy9TGZDH6AjmVhP
(edit the node address too)
```

And don't forget to check that your p2p port isn't blocked by the firewall.

Note, that's just one option for bootnode definition, there are ipv6 and DNS methods too, but this is the simplest option for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to set a private netwrok on two computers.
on your first computer generate a `customSpec.json` file of your project  and insert address of validators,session keys and all in your `customSpec.json` then generate a `customSpecRaw` and run the private network commanad..
Then on your second computer send your project binary,`customSpecRaw`file and your first node local identity with your ip address
now you are ready to run second node on your computer using your private netwrok command.